# Writing a webpack or babel plugin to compile static property into stylesheet

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'd like to declare my styles (stylus) inside of my React component classes as such. Preferably while also utilizing CSS modules:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.hello} />
    );
  }

  static styles = `
    .hello
      display block
  `;
}
```

or even perhaps

```
const styles = stylus`
  .hello
    display block
`;

const HelloWorld = () => <div className={styles.hello} />
```

The goal here is to compile the styles into a stylesheet via stylus (or another preprocessor), strip the `style` block from the resulting javascript bundle, and access styles through CSS modules and the `className` property in JSX. I'd prefer to have these compiled at compile time (babel/webpack) rather than at runtime.

I'm not necessarily looking for hard and fast code, but any direction would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if all of this is even possible, although some of it definitely should be. I understand that accessing styles via `styles.` may not be feasible.

I've never written a babel or webpack plugin so I barely know where to start. Most of the documentation and tutorials that I read didn't seem to get me where I wanted to go.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not possible, but there is a workaround; unfortunately, the answer might taste like bathtub gin. As you are probably aware, you cannot directly `require` Stylus. Accordingly, your forced to use a Stylus loader which you have two options, stylus-loader or Walmarts [stylus-relative-loader](https://github.com/walmartlabs/stylus-relative-loader), I would recommend the latter. Here is where things get a bit convoluted. Since you want to use CSS modules and compile the styles into a stylesheet, you will have to use the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

Long story short, if you are using Webpack 1.x here's an example configuration of the loader which you will need to implement into your Webpack config, which uses extract-text-webpack-plugin, css-modules, and stylus-relative-loader.

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.styl$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!stylus-relative-loader')
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')
  ]
```

From here all you need to do is move your Stylus to a separate file like `my-styles.styl` and then `require` it into your React component like so.

```
const styles = require('./my-styles.styl')

const HelloWorld = () => <div className={styles.hello} />
```

PS. Sorry, if this is not what you're looking for but my "reputation" does not allow me to ask questions via comments nor can I use more than two links.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. From what I gather, I can build something that will take `static styles = '.css { }'` out of a class and compile/concat it into a stylesheet, however, the implementation that I've initially landed on is hacky and ugly at best. What I suppose is not plausible at the moment is then accessing that stylesheet via CSS modules. Even if I can only solve the first half, it's still something I'd like to pursue, but obviously a complete, sane solution would be ideal. I'll follow up if I come up with anything usable.